# Promote to global value set is disabled for my organization

Tags: picklist, global-picklist

Promote to global value set is disabled for picklist. I can see the version of org is summer 17.

Answer (score 5):

did you mean, the promote to global picklist button greyed out? if yes, then most probably you have record type in object, follow the steps in this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233121&type=1).

Else it can be one of the reasons mentioned in this  [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_picklists_global_value_sets.htm)

Briefly it can be due to

1. For each record type, you need to add values (OR)/(AND)
2. You can only promote fields that have fewer than 1,000 values (both active and inactive) (OR)/(AND)
3. You can only promote restricted picklists. If you want to promote an unrestricted picklist, first convert it to a restricted picklist

Comment: I have the same issue, @night crawler can you please update the broken links?

Anyways, I have active record types but the only thing I needed to do was to make the picklist restricted and then I was able to promote.